# Go言語をGoogle Colab上で動かす方法

Tags: go, google-colaboratory

Go言語をGoogle Colab上で動かす方法を探しています。

ネットサーチして大きく3つの方法を試しました。

1. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aoHKfyD2WT03Sjm0hHIdTPxa8z_ZiXly?usp=sharing
2. https://qiita.com/dauuricus/items/e83dfa7955f8239d8542
3. https://qiita.com/kei0425/items/19bebc966dcf50e5af2e

#1は途中でエラーが発生します。

#2
#1の問題改善を#2で行っています。
必要な条件はすべてインストールできますが、いざimport "fmt"を行うと以下のエラーが出ます。

```
import "fmt"
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

#3
これだけは上手く行きますが、いちいちファイルに保存する必要があり、長いコードを書く時には若干めんどくさいことになってしまっています。

Go言語をColab上で動かした経験があれば、ご教授していただけると大変助かります
よろしくお願いします

Comment: Go 向けの [オンラインエディタも存在しますが](https://go.dev/play/) 、あくまで Colab での実行が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。少しコードが長いのと、pythonなどほかのコードとも一緒に連動させたいため、なんとかColab上で動かす方法を探しています。